# Android GLSurfaceView.queueEvent equivalent on iOS?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

In Android you can run code from the UI thread on the `GLThread` with this

```
glSurfaceView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //your code
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I do this in Swift on iOS? It's so elegant on Android I was wondering if there is an equivalent?

Comment: Are you just trying to run something on the background thread? Is there a specific reason you want to execute code on the UI thread? Generally speaking, you should leave the UI thread to its own, just so you can avoid "stalling" the app from the user's perspective with long operations.